# How can we copy data from .csv to .xlsx file . only when column header are same

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

### Heading ##I want to compare column header if they are same then only copy that particular column from .csv to excel

```
.csv file example Table :-
Name  | city  | PhoneNo | DOB
ankit |lucknow| xyz     | aug8
rohan |kanpur | lmn     | march30


.xlsx file example Table:-
Name  | PhoneNo |DOB     (overwrite the data of only those column which are already present)
Arpit |  mnc    |may20
sam   |   def   |dec21
ram   |   kjh   |jan01



i want to copy data from .csv to excel 

final xlsx will :-

Name    |PhoneNo   | DOB
ankit   |xyz       |aug8
rohan   |lmn       |march30
```

Comment: please provide a minimal example

Comment: i have edited the table please have a look @Deusdeorum

Comment: code is not working bro @Deusderoum

Comment: works fine, you will have to change the `pd.read_excel()` and `pd.read_csv()` to read your actual files. Or edit your question with your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can check If the columns in the .csv are represented in the .xlsx and write to a new excel or overwrite the current one if that's the case.

```
df_xlsx = pd.read_excel('excelfile.xlsx')
df_csv = pd.read_csv('csvfile.csv')

if all(elem in df_csv.columns.tolist() for elem in df_xlsx.columns.tolist()):
    df_csv[df_xlsx.columns.tolist()].to_excel('new_excelfile.xlsx')
else:
    print('cols not in csv:' ,list(set(df_xlsx.columns.tolist())-set(df_csv.columns.tolist())))
```